# Jquery mobile page structure

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I built a jquery mobile site a while back and I have recently been expanding on it and noticing performance issues. I believe it is because I constructed the site using a multi-page set up where a single php file houses the following pages:

**ALL_PAGES.PHP**

```
    <html>
    <head>
    /* external css and js files */
    </head>
    <body>

     <div date-role="page" id="main">
          <div class="page_link">
              page 1
          </div> 

          <div class="page_link">
              page 2
          </div> 

          <div class="page_link">
              page 3
          </div>

    </div>


    <div date-role="page" id="page 1">
          <div class="page_link">
              main
          </div>     

          <div class="page_link">
              page 2
          </div> 

          <div class="page_link">
              page 3
          </div>

    </div>

    <div date-role="page" id="page 2">

          <div class="page_link">
              main
          </div>     

          <div class="page_link">
              page 1
          </div>


          <div class="page_link">
              page 3
          </div>

    </div>

    <div date-role="page" id="page 3">

          <div class="page_link">
              main
          </div> 

          <div class="page_link">
              page 1
          </div> 

          <div class="page_link">
              page 2
          </div>


    </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

I want to break away from this multi-page setup on one php file, and move to a setup where each page is a separate php file. To accomplish this I took the html from each page and moved it to its own php page. Then I added href links in replace of the mobile.change() functions I used for the "page_link" classes.

**MAIN.PHP**

```
 <html>
    <head>
     external css and js files
    </head>
    <body>
        <div date-role="page" id="page 1">
              <a href="/main.php">
                  main
              </a>        

              <a href="/page_2.php">
                  page 2
              </a> 

              <a href="/page_3.php">
                  page 3
              </a>

        </div>


        </body>

    </html>
```

**PAGE_1.PHP**

```
        <div date-role="page" id="page 1">
              <a href="/main.php">
                  main
              </a>        

              <a href="/page_2.php">
                  page 2
              </a> 

              <a href="/page_3.php">
                  page 3
              </a>

        </div>
```

**PAGE_2.PHP**

```
        <div date-role="page" id="page 2">
              <a href="/main.php">
                  main
              </a>            

              <a href="/page_1.php">
                  page 1
              </a> 

              <a href="/page_3.php">
                  page 3
              </a>

        </div>
```

**PAGE_3.PHP**

```
        <div date-role="page" id="page 3">
              <a href="/main.php">
                  main
              </a>            

              <a href="/page_1.php">
                  page 1
              </a> 

              <a href="/page_2.php">
                  page 2
              </a>

        </div>
```

The site works fine except when the user hits the refresh button in the browser. When that happens each page loses access to any external css and js files located on the main page. I am fairly new to JQM so any advice would be helpful.

Comment: When user hits refresh on pages other than main? If so, just in case, add JS and css links in head. However, when refreshing it should go to main page or the first visited link. What versions of jquery and JQM are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#whicheverPage").trigger("pagecreate");
```

It will apply enhancements for all added content within the page when loaded.

Comment: where would i add this?

Comment: Into a document ready handler on the page you need marking up.

Comment: `.ready()` isn't recommended to be used in JQM. Also, JQM enhances pages on load, if pages aren't enhanced, this means JQM isn't loaded.